# Slideshow of web page

Tags: web-part

new to sharepoint, I'm for now just an explorer.
For our sharepoint we want to display on a screen a display than can rotate between several page like a slideshow.
A screen which display some of the page of our sharepoint page.
I don't find a app in sharepoint.
Have you an idea ? External page with url ?

Thanx for your help for a poor beginner.

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: it seems to be server 2013.